# how to get different hidden field values in multiple form in a page

Tags: jquery

in a page i have 2 forms where both having a hidden field named operation(same name for both form)

```
included jquery.min-1.5.js & jquery-ui.min-1.8.js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#get_val').live('click', function() {
    alert($('#operation').val());
  });
});
</script>
<form id="form_como" name="form_como" action="go.php" method="post">
  //some code.....
  <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" value="first">
  <input type="button" name="get_val" id="get_val" value="Get Val"/>
</form>

<br />

<form id="form_como2" name="form_como2" action="" method="post">
  //some code.....
  <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" value="second">
  <input type="button" name="get_val" id="get_val" value="Get Val"/>
</form>
```

When i click "Get Val" button i always get 'first" (for both cases). but i need the value of the button which one i have clicked.

Answer (score 0):

//use unique id in both of the form

```
<form id="form_como" name="form_como" action="go.php" method="post">
  //some code.....
  <input type="hidden" name="operation" id="operation" value="first">
  <input type="button" name="get_val" id="get_val" value="Get Val"/>
</form>

<br />

<form id="form_como2" name="form_como2" action="" method="post">
  //some code.....
  <input type="hidden" name="operation2" id="operation2" value="second">
  <input type="button" name="get_val2" id="get_val2" value="Get Val"/>
</form>
```

**update** if cant change id then use by name

```
 $('input[name=get_val]').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).prev().val());
  });
```

refrence **[prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)**

Comment: for some reason i can't rename. i would like to get value by using form name.

Comment: Thanks but i can't change name or id. is there are any way to get values like form-name.hidden-field-name ?

Comment: in case the previous is another element (not operation), then you will get the wrong value. So I think we should use find element by name or id before we get the value

Comment: Now you can do that by update result no need to change ids and thanks for focus @ha nguyen

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name=get_val]").bind({
    click: function(event) {
       alert($("input[name=operation]" , $(this).parent()).val());
    }
});
});
```

If you use `prev()`, then you only get the value for the previous element. If the previous element of button is another element (not an operation), then you will get the wrong value.